# Sqlite rawQuery retirn 0 rows

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Many times I tried using the rawQuery() to get values but the cursor always returns 0 row although there are valid rows that match the conditions. here is my code:

```
public Cursor getChapIdForAudit(String auditid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //String sql="SELECT DISTINCT  ChapterID FROM Results WHERE AuditID = "+auditid;
Cursor c=   sp.rawQuery("SELECT ChapterID FROM Results WHERE AuditID ="+auditid,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

Caller code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i= getIntent();
        String auditid=i.getExtras().getString("audit_id");

        ResultsTableManager results= new ResultsTableManager(ScoringRecordsActivity.this);
        results.open();
    Cursor chapIdCursor=null;
    chapIdCursor= results.getChapIdForAudit(auditid);

    System.out.println(chapIdCursor.getCount());



    }
```

Comment: what I actually need is a select distinct query, but that didn't work, so I tried normal select, that too did not work.

Comment: If you have changed your database since first install, you might have to uninstall the app completely and reinstall in order to get the new tables.

Comment: I am aware of that, but my db has not changed.

Comment: In that case it is not easy to determine the origin of your problem as it could be so many things. Do you get any rows if you simply query "SELECT * FROM Results"?

Comment: Actually, if I check the cursor length in this function it is right, but when I return it to another activity it becomes 0;

Comment: Do you close the cursor or the database at some place? Can you add the code where you call getChapIdForAudit and see a size of 0?

Comment: I have added that code just now

Comment: That is strange, as you say the size is correct inside the method.. and you are positive that auditid is in fact a valid id and not null or something else?

Comment: Does the `AuditID` column contains string or integer values?